# jQuery superfish menu TypeError: o is undefined clearTimeout(o.sfTimer);

Tags: jquery, superfish

I have 2 menus on my site both being called with the `.superfish()` below.

```
$("ul.sf-menu").superfish();
```

The code works fine if we're actually in the footer menu, but if we're in the header menu I get the error below:

```
TypeError: o is undefined
clearTimeout(o.sfTimer);
```

Is this a bug with the superfish menu or with my code?

I'm using version 1.7.2 of superfish and version 1.7.1 of jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the classes `sf-js-enabled sf-shadow` on my `ul.sf-menu` and it caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

yeah thats true. i had same problem ;

my menu was

```
ul id="main-nav" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow"
```

and i have changed like

```
ul id="main-nav" class="sf-menu"
```

and problem has been done.